# Проблема с переводом слова which на русский язык

Tags: английский-язык

Всем привет! У меня есть такая фраза:

> Returns the value and key of the value in table `t` which returns `true`
> when `fn` is called on it.

Когда я читаю её, мой мозг испытывает stack overflow! Ниже я объясню почему,
сперва хочу показать свой вольный перевод этого текста, который мне удалось сделать
только после того как я действительно осознал, как эта функция работает:

> Возвращает значение и ключ значения в таблице `t`, которое даёт
> истину, когда `fn` принимает его как аргумент.

Прежде всего хочу отметить, что *"called on it"* я перевёл совсем иначе, потому что
это само по себе довольно корявое выражение. Функции не могут вызываться на чём либо,
они могут лишь принимать значения в качестве аргументов, но давайте отбросим этот момент,
он не так важен.

Важно для меня здесь то, что в русском языке слово "который" несёт в себе контекстную информацию при склонении. Если я говорю *"...возвращает значение и ключ значения, котор**ОЕ**..."*, то из этого следует, что речь идёт о значении, а не о ключе.

Но в фразе *"Returns the value and key of the value in table `t` **which** returns `true` when `fn` is called on **it**."* я не понимаю, куда ссылаются **which** и **it**! На **value**? на **key**? может на **table**?

Интуитивно мне кажется, что оно должно ссылаться на последнее слово. Я предполагаю, что речь
идёт о таблице и теоретически таблицы действительно могут возвращать значения, как и функции,
но моя догадка лишь вводит меня в глубокое заблуждение, потому что на самом деле `true` здесь должна возвращать именно функция!

Собственно вопрос в том, как носители языка понимают, о чём они говорят?

Comment: У вас родной английский?

Comment: А предыдущую английскую фразу можете привести? Пока понятно только, что таблица t задает булеву функцию Fn ("ключи" при "значениях", с которых начата фраза, "разрешенный" ли аргумент, value) для набора значений аргумента, но неясно, почему при обращении к ней за значением Fn "возвращается" именно 1. Английское which в таких конструкциях не обязательно относится к существительному ("который"), а может ссылаться на целое действие ("что возвращает", "а это возвращает" и т. п.).

Comment: @ИгорьБолотов Родной у меня русский. Вопрос в том, как носители английского понимают, на что у них указывают "слова-укзатели", такие как which, this, it, если в языке нет склонений, облегчающих эту задачу, как в русском.

Comment: @Alex_ander я понял вас, это интересная мысль, спасибо. Но по-моему даже в таком случае, здесь невозможно понять, что конкретно имел ввиду автор.